# Inverse of sum of identity matrix and a special matrix

Tags: inverse

How to calculate the inverse of the matrix $(I_{m+1}+A)$, where $A$ is given by
$
\[
A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & a1_{m}^{T} \\
a1_{m} & 1_{m}1_{m}^{T}%
\end{array}%
\right) ,
%
$
with $1_{m}$ is a vector of ones of length $m$, $I_{m}$ is an identity matrix. $a$ is a constant that is different from zero and 1. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think the matrix $I_(m+1)+A$ is an arrow matrix in your reference.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm going to delete that link to avoid giving the impression that this question has been answered elsewhere.